# Ubuntu server 20.04 with netplan and two 1G ports that are on the same subnet

Tags: networking, netplan

I am getting collocation service for my hardware that has `4x1G` ports on the same network card. Two of the ports are plugged and they correspond to eno5 and eno6 interfaces on my operating system which is Ubuntu server 20.04. The provider has assigned me a `/24` ipv4 subnet and they say I can use both ports on it. Lets consider `xx.xx.xx.0/24` is my ip range and `xx.xx.xx.1` is my gateway. The scenario I want to run is to assign `xx.xx.xx.2` to `eno5` and `xx.xx.xx.3` to `eno6`. The behavior I expect is that the traffic coming to `xx.xx.xx.3` from `eno6` also go out through `eno6`.

I have come up with following `netplan` config so far which is adjusted within two seperate config files:

Config related to `eno5` is `/etc/netplan/conf5.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno5:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - xx.xx.xx.2/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: xx.xx.xx.1
          table: 500
          metric: 500
      routing-policy:
        - from: xx.xx.xx.2/24
          table: 500
```

Config related to `eno6` is `/etc/netplan/conf6.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno6:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - xx.xx.xx.3/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: xx.xx.xx.1
          table: 600
          metric: 600
      routing-policy:
        - from: xx.xx.xx.3/24
          table: 600
```

Now, I have two IPs working. I mean if I ping from a remote machine both xx.xx.xx.2 and xx.xx.xx.3 respond successfully. I also can run successful pings inside my machine:

```
ping -I eno5 google.com
ping -I eno6 google.com
```

Every thing is good up until I want to ssh to `xx.xx.xx.3` from a remote machine and download a large file. When I try to do so after that the download is complete I don't see `eno6` tx count moved much. Instead tx count on `eno5` moves hugely. I check the counts using:

```
> ip -s link show eno5
link/ether d4:f5:ef:4b:54:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
237309112    35714    0       901     0       913     
TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
991989133    54400     0       0       0       0  
> ip -s link show eno6
link/ether d4:f5:ef:4b:54:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
153728525    19980    0       933     0       945     
TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
2582       29       0       0       0       0
```

I conclude that the ssh request I am sending to `xx.xx.xx.3` (`eno6`) is responded through `eno5`. Am I right?

Which part of my policy-routing and or the whole config is wrong that I am ending up like this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few nights of headache, it turned out that this scenario does not need any policy routing. I just needed to determine different metrics for each interface default route. Here is the final working configuration:

Config related to `eno5` is `/etc/netplan/conf5.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno5:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - xx.xx.xx.2/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: xx.xx.xx.1
          metric: 500
```

Config related to `eno6` is `/etc/netplan/conf6.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno6:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
      - xx.xx.xx.3/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: xx.xx.xx.1
          metric: 600
```